# Реализация алгоритма Полига — Хеллмана

Tags: c++

[Алгоритм Полига — Хеллмана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80)

Пытаюсь реализовать по примеру.

Получается такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int powmod(int a, int b, int m) {
    int res = 1;

    while (b > 0)
        if (b & 1) {
            res = (res * a) % m;
            --b;
        }
        else {
            a = (a * a) % m;
            b >>= 1;
        }
        return res % m;
}

int algorith(int a, int b, int p)
{
    int p1;
    int q;
    int z=0;
    int m;
    int x = 0;

    p1 = sqrt(p - 1);
    z = 13*powmod(3, 17 - 1 - pow(2,2), p);
    q = powmod(b, (p - 1) / 2, p) - p;
    if (q == 1)
        q = 0;
    else q = 1;
    x = q;
    for (int i = 1; i < p1; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            z = b*powmod(a, p - 1 - q, p) % p;

        else
            z = z*powmod(a, p - 1 - q - pow(2, i - 1), p) % p;
        if (z > 0)
            z -= p;
        else z += p;
            m = (p - 1) / pow(2, i + 1);
            q = powmod(b, (p - 1) / 2, p) - p;
            if (q == 1)
                q = 0;
            else q = 1;
        x += q * pow(2, i);
    }
    return x;
}

void main()
{
    cout<<algorith(3, 11, 17);
    system("pause");
}
```

POWMOD нужен для возведения числа по модулю.Проходит все по примеру, но на последнем этапе должно быть z3=1, а у меня z3=15.

В чем ошибка?

Я наверное не правильно этот z, считаю, но как его правильно, ни как не могу понять. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас не хватает скобочек (или форматирование неправильное). Всегда делайте новый блок после `if` / `else` и т.п.

Comment: вроде все на месте. Там, где считается z3=13*2^2. Почему-то становится, -4*4. Этого я не понял. Если не переводить 13 в -4, то считает у меня правильно.